# Detect if div is displayed - differences vs empty div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to know if div is not visible? I tried different ways but in all cases, if there is a div with CSS `display: none` it considers it as "full". I could check "if display none or empty". But Is there any way that could detect all the cases?

```js
 // Different ways to say that a div is empty:
 //var empty = $("#a").html() == "";
 //var empty = $("#a").text() == "";
 //var empty = $('#a').text().length == 0
 //var empty = $('#a').contents().length == 0;
 //var empty = $('#a').is(':empty');
 
 // if there is a div display none, it's considered full:
 if ( empty ) {
  $("#check").text("a is empty");
 }
 else {
  $("#check").text("a is full");
 }
```

```css
#a { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id='a'>
 <div>something</div>
</div> 

<div id='check'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have noted, whether or not an element is "empty" depends on what you consider empty, so you may have to trim white space, etc to get what you are after in different browsers. In order to include `display: none` elements in your definition of empty, you can check an element's computed display style using jquery `.css()`:

```
var display = $('#a').css('display');

if (display === 'none') {
  // do something
}
```

I don't know of a one liner that you could use to capture whether or not an element is either "empty" or not displayed. Below is a relatively simple framework to evaluate whether or not elements are "empty" or not displayed, but you may need to add additional criteria (i.e. visibility, whether or not you consider white space empty, etc).

```js
const elems = $('.foo');

elems.each(function() {
  let content = $(this).html().length;
  let display = $(this).css('display');
  if (content && display !== 'none') {
    console.log(this.id, 'displayed and not empty');
  } else {
    console.log(this.id, 'empty or not displayed');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="foo" id="bar" style="display: none;">
  <div>
    Something
  </div>
</div>
<div class="foo" id="baz"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be checking either if the `div` has child elements (which you already did) and in addition to that check if any of the elements is actually visible:

```js
var elems = $('#a').contents();
var empty = elems.length == 0;
var containsVisibleElement = false;
elems.each(function(i, v) { //loop though all contained elemetns
  containsVisibleElement = $(this).is(':visible'); //check if element is visible
  if (containsVisibleElement ) {
    return false; //break out of loop as one visible is enough for our check
  }
});

if (empty || !containsVisibleElement) {
  $("#check").text("a is empty");
} else {
  $("#check").text("a is full");
}
```

```css
#a div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='a'>
  <div>something</div>
</div>

<div id='check'></div>
```